# F# - Converting a for-each loop to a lambda expression

Tags: json, foreach, lambda, f#

I've been struggling with figuring out how to convert a for-each loop to a lambda expression (purely just to facilitate for a more functional style of coding).

```
for airlineData in allAirlinesData do
    match airlineData with
    | (airlineCode, data) -> 
        let airlineFullName = data.GetProperty("full_name").AsString()
        let capacity = data.GetProperty("capacity").AsString()
        let aircraftCount = data.GetProperty("aircraft_count").AsArray()
        ...
    | _ -> ...
```

`allAirlinesData` is a `(string * JsonValue)[]`

Is there any easier way of applying a value to `airlineFullName` for example without using a for-each loop and perhaps a lambda expression instead?

Thanks

Comment: If you are parsing JSON data, you might want to check out the JSON type provider: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for this:

```
allAirlinesData |> Array.iter (fun (airlineCode, data) ->
        let airlineFullName = ...
        ...
    )
```

Hard to say which looks better though. This removes the `match` line, but adds the extra parentheses that need to be closed again.

If you want to make the code more functional, the main question is: why are you iterating in the first place? Both `for ... in ... do` and `.iter` are imperative constructs that execute side-effects instead of returning a value. I wouldn't call one more functional than the other. For a more functional style, you might want to look for something that builds a new, immutable value from the data, such as a map or fold. *Though I don't know your use case, so this may or may not be a good choice.*

**Wild assumptions**

As a wildly guessed example, if I assume that `airlineCode` is used as a key and not used to build the airline data, a functional program to import the data might look like this:

```
type Airline =
    { FullName : string
      ... }

    static member ofJson (data : JsonValue) =
        { FullName = data.GetProperty("full_name").AsString()
          ... }

let airlines =
    allAirlinesData
    |> Map.ofArray
    |> Map.map Airline.ofJson
```